# where to find "ConsumeContainerWhitespace" in visual studio 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

where to find "ConsumeContainerWhitespace" in visual studio 2015

Comment: click on the grey space outside of the report area and look in the properties tab.

Comment: it only shows border , fill and position in the properties tab

Comment: You're clicking in the report page and you're seeing the Body properties. Click outside the report borders in the bluish gray area that should be the Report properties. Then look at the properties window. Under the "Other" properties it should be in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When you click in the report body**, its **not** there

[image]

---

**But, when you click at proper place**, it **is** there

[image]

Comment: i just had to close visual studio and open it up again for some reason, Thank you very much

Comment: yup, at times it may happen, but often times _we_ are also wrong to get things right : )

Comment: well, the reason i was looking for this is i am having a white blank space on the right of my SSRS report using the localhost , and i  thought changing the consume container white space to true will get rid of it but it didnt actually .

Comment: ah!, you may have to manually put limits to your report body , by using the size property in the properties.. (First Image)

Comment: yea ,i'll give it a try and see whats gonna happen

Comment: and you can do the same, initailly, by actually dragging the report body to specified size as well..